# Связь много кнопок+ форма, определить нажатую кнопку

Tags: jquery

Есть много однотипных кнопок, по нажатию на каждую появляется однотипная форма. После нажатия субмит на форме, нужно чтобы кнопка, которая вызвала форму стала неактивной. Сейчас после субмита отключаются все формы. Как сделать, чтобы отключалась только одна кнопка? Понятно, что можно получить ее айди через this, но как передать это дальше??

```
<button id = "btn3" class = "btn btn-danger" >Buy</button>
        <button id = "btn4" class = "btn btn-danger" >Buy</button>
        <button id = "btn5" class = "btn btn-danger" >Buy</button>

 <script type="text/javascript">

      $(function()   {

          var btn =  $('.btn-danger');
          var form = $('#myform');
          var formbtn =   $('#submit');

           btn.on ('mouseup', function(){
                var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

                 form.toggle(200);


       });

     formbtn.on('mouseup', function(){
          btn.html('bought!');
            btn.attr('disabled', 'disebled');
              form.html('Мы вам перезвоним!!!').delay(2000).toggle(500);
       });


    });
```

Comment: передать дальше куда?

Comment: Ну я думаю в обработчик нажатия formbtn - нажатия субмит на форме, ведь после него кнопка должна отключаться.

Comment: кнопку отключить проще простого `$(function(){
   $('button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled')
   });
  });`

Comment: Мне нужно отключить кнопку, которая открыла форму,  по нажатию на кнопку на этой форме.

Comment: вы вообще хоть поняли что сказали? `нужно отключить кнопку, которая открыла форму, по нажатию на кнопку на этой форме`

Comment: Да! Есть кнопка, открывающая форму. На форме есть другая кнопка, и когда я ее нажимаю, хочу чтобы форма закрылась, а кнопка, одна из многих, которая открыла эту форму, стала неактивной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хтмл кода не вижу, но логику показать можно вот так

```js
  $(function() {
    $('.rows').on('click', '.open', function() {
      $(this).parent().children('form').show();
      $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

    $('.rows').on('click', '.close', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('form').hide();
    });
  });
```

```css
form {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rows">
  <div class="row">
    <button class="open">Кнопка</button>
    <form>форма 1
      <button class="close">Кнопка закрыть</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="open">Кнопка</button>
    <form>форма 2
      <button class="close">Кнопка закрыть</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="open">Кнопка</button>
    <form>форма 3
      <button class="close">Кнопка закрыть</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```